# How to allow a specific domain to load in iFrame in Edge browser

Tags: asp.net, iframe, microsoft-edge, content-security-policy

I have an `ASP.Net` `MVC application` (named ***`app1.com`***) that allow another domain (named ***`app2.com`***) to load it in an `iframe`.
I have set up `Content-Security-Policy` header using *`frame-ancestors app2.com`*.

It has worked very well in **Chrome** and **Firefox**. But it **does not work in Edge**. It says that :

> Unknown directive 'frame-ancestors' in Content-Security-Policy -
>   directive will be ignored.

I have tried to use `frame-src` but it is not effective. Anybody can help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the frame-ancestors directive is [now supported in Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/whats-new/edgehtml-15#content-security-policy-level-2).

Because of the way CSP works, unknown directives are ignored. What this means if a non-supporting browser sees a frame-ancestors directive, it will frame the page no matter what the framing page is - allowing that page to frame it (but not preventing other pages from doing the same).

If you only want the one site to frame the page, even in old browsers, you can use the [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) header like this:

```
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://app2.com/
```

Browsers that support frame-ancestors will ignore X-Frame-Options when the two of them are used together on the same page.